# Uncheck a checkbox from within ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to reset the state of a checkbox to `false` from within the action-method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(RegistrationModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //...
    }

    model.AcceptTerms = false;
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the Razor view-template:

```
<input asp-for="AcceptTerms"/>
```

But after I post the form, the checkbox stays checked.

How can I programmatically uncheck a checked checkbox from within my action method please?

Thank you in advance!

I tried the code above and I tried to use the old `@Html.CheckBoxFor(...)` but with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following (`Register.cshtml`):

```
@model RegistrationModel 

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Register" method="post">
   <input asp-for="AcceptTerms" type="checkbox" />
   <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

---

For more details see: [Tag Helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-input-tag-helper)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there a way to use this with tag-helpers? (like <form asp-controller="..." asp-action="...">)

Comment: @Sam: See my update with the tag helper above. But, actually you don't need to specify   `type="checkbox"`; the `<input asp-for="AcceptTerms" />` will render correct checkbox tag too.